# iPhone: How to hide scroll indicator in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextfield, uipickerview

I'm using a UITextField inside a UIPickerView to show a picture together with text. When scrolling in the picker the vertical scroll indicator shows up. How can I make it disappear?

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

      UITextField *field = (UITextField*) view;

      if (view == nil) {

          field = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)]autorelease];
          field.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   // overriding highlighted selection
          field.delegate = self; 

      }
      ...
```

Comment: Why are you using a text field instead of a label?

Comment: Because I thought it was easy to use its "leftView" property to show a pic.